# How to Export a Document Library to Excel from SharePoint 2010 using a custom button?

Tags: 2010, document-library, excel, ribbon, custom-actions

I need to do the same as this little fantastic button in the sharepoint ribbon. It allows users to export a document library to an excel spreadsheet. I posted a screenshot below.

[image: export button in ribbon]

I would like to have the same, but visible on my main page (not in a ribbon but in the main page body instead). How can I do this kind of custom button please ? If there is a standard procedure to do it, it's even better! Thanks.

Comment: You mean like using a link? Such as this one: {Site URL}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={List GUID}&View={View GUID}&CacheControl=1 from the post [Create Link to Export Library Contents to Excel](https://www.formsonfire.com/office-365/create-link-to-export-library-contents-to-excel/)

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I mean. So why don't you post it as an answer to allow me to approve :) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like using a link? Such as this one: `{Site URL}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={List GUID}&View={View GUID}&CacheControl=1` from the post [Create Link to Export Library Contents to Excel](https://www.formsonfire.com/office-365/create-link-to-export-library-contents-to-excel/)